# What's a good web app for keeping a daily log?

Tags: webapp-rec

I find that [RememberTheMilk](http://rememberthemilk.com) is great for keeping track of what I **should** be doing but I also like to keep track of what I'm **actually** doing -- where the time actually goes.  Right now, I'm using pen & paper which is starting to feel a bit quaint to me.  (Querying seems to involve more paper cuts that suits me.)  I'd like to find a web app which can keep this data for me -- bonus points if it syncs to desktop/phone/etc.

Edit: I'm not really looking for a time tracker -- just somewhere that I can enter what I'm working on.  A time-tracker seems like (a) overkill and (b) something that might keep track of what I'm doing on my PC but not "meeting with KK & JK re: Project Boofus."

Answer (score 2):

If you more a visual person you can use a sticky note whiteboard like [yommoo.com](http://www.yommoo.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a note application [Google Notes](http://www.google.com/notebook/fullpage) or [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/). I'm pretty sure that Evernote has a desktop client and a mobile application (at least for Android).

Comment: An Evernote app is available for iPhone.

Comment: Wow. +1 for Google Notes. I clicked the link and discovered that I created a series of entries in it during the summer of 2006...  I don't remember using it, but it really looks like the perfect application for my needs!

Comment: As of July 2012, Google Notebook has shut down and all Notebook data should now be in Google Docs - http://www.google.com/googlenotebook/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

For simple quick little notes, why not Twitter?  It's easy, it forces you to keep your notes short (if that's what you're looking for), there are a million interfaces for it by now, and anybody else interested in your log (a spouse, a stalker, etc.) can follow you (if you allow).

Comment: The problem with Twitter is that it sucks for browsing the history of your tweets.

Comment: Twitter does not guarantee ability to browse old tweets. (how old?  Hasn't been defined.)  They are in the business of streaming the here and now.

Comment: I'm liking the idea of Twitter-style quick notes, but that lack of history is a problem.

Comment: It's definitely a risk in that regard.  I wonder (and may post this as a separate question) if there are any Twitter client interfaces that address this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a calendaring app.  Google Calendar lets you create additional calendars that can be separate from your time management.  Then, switch to Agenda View for chronological list of events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Erbix Pluto](http://www.erbix.com/pluto/) to keep track of your todos in a simple manner. By using the included activity log feature, you can go back in time and review your progress.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Twitter and the [Twitter Google Calendar bot](http://twitter.com/#!/gcal). You just DM what you're doing and it gets stored in your GCal. Basically you're just using Twitter as an input mechanism. Your data is stored in GCal. Just make sure not to put any dates in the DM though or GCal will parse it and try to associate that event with a date.

Answer (score -1):

[iDoneThis.com](http://idonethis.com) can be what you are looking for.

Comment: How does it help?